# Good sites for learning Active Directory Operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

Could anybody help me to list Some Good Sites that are describing about Complete AD Operations.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are rather scarce indeed:

- [How to do just about everything in AD from C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103230539/http://www.codeproject.com:80/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx?)

and then some AD articles in the MSDN magazine:

- [New Ways to Manage Active Directory using the .NET Framework 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues)
- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues)

of course of the AD sites on MSDN:

- [System.DirectoryServices namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
- [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

and of course the ultimate book on System.DirectoryServices:

- [The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170)

[image]

and the [website accompanying the book](http://www.directoryprogramming.net/)

- [Richard Mueller's web site](https://www.rlmueller.net/) (mostly reference materials)